# How to add new data to array by for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

`data1:[{ a : datA},{ b : datB},{ c : datC},{ d : datD}]`

I need to add 1 and 2 push to object like below

`data1:[{ a : datA, r : 1},{ b : datB, r : 2},{ c : datC, r : 1},{ d : datD, r : 2}]`

Thank you for helping me very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .map() function to loop through data1 adding property r with if statment to check if r=2 or r=1

```
data1=[{ a :'datA'},{ b : 'datB'},{ c : 'datC'},{ d : 'datD'}];
    var i=1;
    data1.map(element=>{
        element.r=i;
        i= i==1?2:1;
 });
 console.log(data1);
```

Comment: You don't need `map` for this. You can just use `forEach`.

Comment: Is map() loop through the array like forEach or not ?   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: Yes, but the purpose of `map` is to transform the array into a new one. If your intention is to just loop and mutate the old array, `forEach` is the one to use.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f Here is the difference between map and forEach

Comment: We can use both of them of course but map() execution speed is better also with map we can save the original array and create new one.

Answer (score 0):

as they sayed in the comment of Osama's awnser you can do a for in loop or even a foreach.

```
​​var array = [{ a : "datA"},{ b : "datB"},{ c : "datC"},{ d : "datD"}];
var index = 1;
for (const key in array) {

    if (array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = array[key];
        element.r = index;

    }
    index == 1 ? index++:index--;
}
console.log(array);
```